# What are the entities namespaces and alias in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

In the documentation I saw this method:

```
addEntityNamespace($alias, $namespace);
```

But I can't find anywhere what is it about.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Entity namespaces are a shortcut to aliasing Entities when pointing to other classes.
A good example of an entity namespace is inside DQL queries.

When you define a namespace, like: ->addEntityNamespace('app', 'Application\Entity');
You can then refer to them easily. In a DQL sample, instead of write this:

```
SELECT u FROM Application\Entity\User u
```

You can do that:

```
SELECT u FROM app:User u
```

I hope this helps. =)

Cheers,